# How to reduce the number of clicks in Adobe acrobat/windows to save updated pdf file overwriting the existing one?

Tags: windows, pdf, adobe-acrobat, adobe-reader, pdf-reader

I am using the Adobe Acrobat readers to add comments to PDF files but every time I want to exit the file leaving the newer version overwriting the earlier one, I have to jump through several windows popping up asking for confirmation.

Is there any way to configure Adobe Acrobat to have a quicker way to save the newer copy overwriting the older one?